What is the trinity-like relationship between morphisms, functors, natural transformations?
From the ncatlab article Category Theory:

Category theory reflects on itself. Categories are about collections of morphisms. And there are evident morphisms between categories: functors. And there are evident morphisms between functors: natural transformations. This trinity of concepts [...] is what category theory is built on.

Even after studying and applying category theory for some amount of time, I remain mystified by this philosophy. In category theory there seems to be a prevalent sentiment that we really want "category" to mean "a bunch of the same sort of algebraic structure", such as a group. But a group is, in it of itself, a category; and that's how I attempted to understand category theory at first, until I realized what the actual purpose was.
By all means, it appears to me that the notions of "morphism", "functor", and "natural transformation" are the exact same thing; indeed the above quote continues:

In higher category theory this continues with -transfors for all  ∈ ℕ.

Yet this is not at all how morphisms, functors, and natural transformations are treated in the literature and in informal discussion. When a theorem talks about functors, I find myself forced to think about structure-preserving maps in some higher category that I usually can't quite picture. And when the words "natural transformation" show up I cower in fear. People seem to have an understanding of what categories want to be that is absent from the axioms and remains obscure to me: an understanding where thinking of a group as a one-object category feels somewhat obscene and the word "functor" carries with it very different baggage from the word "morphism".
This question is of course imprecise and just asking for intuition / clarification.
As an example of what kind of intuition I am looking for, here is how I would reply to a question asking the same thing but for addition, multiplication, and exponentiation: The way multiplication interacts with addition is rather different from how exponentiation interacts with multiplication -- for example, $(n^a)^b = n^{ab}$ -- but the way tetration interacts with exponentiation offers nothing new to the table, so exponentiation is the last interesting level.
As a more involved example, if someone asked what the deal is with the trinity-like relationship between the real numbers, the complex numbers, and the quaternions, a satisfying answer would be mentioning the 8-periodicity of Clifford algebras over $\mathbb{R}$.
I cannot think of anything similar justifying the morphism, functor, natural transformation trinity.

Keep in mind I am a fellow learner of category theory who has struggled for years without any real mentorship in the subject, and who has had a rough time extracting the spirit of how category theory works.
I think you're on the wrong track with this:

if someone asked what the deal is with the trinity-like relationship between the real numbers, the complex numbers, and the quaternions, a satisfying answer would be mentioning the 8-periodicity of Clifford algebras over ℝ.

I think that there is not anything special that says morphism-functor-naturaltransformation form an exclusive group of three things that capture everything. Rather, I think they are just three cornerstones that all of category starts from.  The three 'basic' real Clifford algebras are more of an example of some exceptional or surprising "finite" phenomenon, such as the sporadic groups, or the results on how many Platonic solids there are in various dimensions and so on.
In category theory, one can talk about morphisms, morphisms of morphisms, morphisms of morphisms of morphisms and so on ad infinitum. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher_category_theory). That hierarchy goes up forever.
One thing I think I've learned is that the objects are not really doing a whole lot: I think they're there mainly to help you say when composability is possible between arrows.  I imagine it a bit as a map where the city names aren't important but the road names are.  That's why I think that one might just say "morphisms are important... so are morphisms between morphsisms... and those morphisms' morphisms too!"
I think higher-category theorists really do continue to take this pattern to heart, but possibly for the rest of us the lowest two or three layers are sufficient to show us the power of what's going on with categories.
I've often thought of how in mechanics we are most often interested in the first two derivatives but not really in higher derivatives - although they are out there!  It seems like a great deal of the most useful stuff is in the first two layers of approximation.  (This may be a spurious analogy though.)
But going back to the original thought: Category theory reflects on itself. You can clearly see this in that not only can we discuss a category of objects and morphisms, but categories themselves are objects with morphisms between them, a sort of self-referential (reflective) statement.
Another very apt statement I've heard is that "category theory is a sort of primordial soup" because frequently you can have two fundamental concepts A and B and phrase each in terms of the other. It's not that they're synonyms, it's just that it's hard (or impossible) to say which one is more fundamental, because they both seem to be giving rise to each other.
And finally let me say something about

In category theory there seems to be a prevalent sentiment that we really want "category" to mean "a bunch of the same sort of algebraic structure", such as a group. But a group is, in it of itself, a category;

I can sympathize with that. Much emphasis is placed on these examples of categories, probably just owing to their accessibility.  Anyhow it is a compelling picture to show how problems in one branch of mathematics could be translated to another and solved using the connection.  Recently while reading the stuff the "applied category theory" school has been producing, I've been realizing that such categories are really overly perfect examples.
It's as if while walking on the beach someone was drawing your attention to sea creature shells shaped like tetrahedrons and cubes and spheres as examples of seashells, but actually all the irregularly shaped shells on the beach are interesting too.
Applied category theorists work with categories one might consider "ad-hoc" (a term they themselves use sometimes) and while they do not have the "crystalline" quality of, say, the category of groups, they do have categorical properties exploitable via category theory.
For me, a compelling example of an ad-hoc category is that of a database schema, where a database instance is simply a functor from this category to the category Set, and database migrations can be considered as natural transformations between functors (database instances.)
